# Patterns for a wizard inside an Android tablet/phone app

Tags: android, wizard, tablet, smartphone

We are rebuilding a banking application for Android tablet and phone. With this banking application you are able to create a savings account. The creation process for phone currently exists out of a wizard with six steps spread across  six screens. For tablet popups are used.

Now I'm wondering what is a common used pattern for a wizard with this many steps on phone as well as tablet? I've looked at a lot of populair Android apps but none of them really contain this kind of wizard and thus do not really show a pattern.

So to come to the question, are there any common used patterns that people here are aware of? Especially for tablet because popups are definitely not done for Android tablet. I'm also aware of the fact that this many screens/steps should be reduced to provide a more simple mobile experience. But you still keep a wizard.

Thanks your insights in advance

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking people to fill in a form to signup - is that correct? Or do you mean encouraging people to get to the form in the first place?

Comment: 6 pages of form filling on a smartphone/tab is too much, it kind of defeats the purpose of the app

Answer (score 1):

- The motive behind using wizards is to keep the user engaged without
  allowing him to go out of the process until and unless he/she
  completes the desired task. This is achieved by limiting his access
  to other actions, functionality available to him normally.
- In such cases pop-up wizards would serve the purpose efficiently in
  most of the cases. But, **since this scenario revolves around usage of
  a tablet** the solution can be a slight work around. Now, what does
  that exactly means ?
- It means using a typical wizard without its attribute of it being on
  a popup. Ultimately, the user should experience it as a wizard and
  not the developers. For the developers it can be simply different
  forms for every step involved in the wizard.

  The image below shows a wizard like behavior on a normal screen/web page -

  [image]

  For an Android App the same solution can be applied as shown in the image below-

  [image]